# Which units do Apache DBCP defaultQueryTimeout expects?

Tags: java, apache-commons-dbcp

The Apache Commons DBCP's [documentation](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/configuration.html) states, that

> defaultQueryTimeout
>   If non-null, the value of this Integer property
>   determines the query timeout that will be used for Statements created
>   from connections managed by the pool. null means that the driver
>   default will be used.

But they forgot to mention which [time] units they expect. The same forgetfulness is in the Javadoc.

I assume that timeout is in seconds, because `validationQueryTimeout` expects timeout in seconds, but it's only an assumption.

So what units apply to the `defaultQueryTimeout`? Also seconds?

Comment: you are right, please see [Statement#setQueryTimeout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#setQueryTimeout-int-).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two values are effectively in seconds.

The wanted informations are available in the Javadoc of the class [BasicDataSource](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/api-2.7.0/org/apache/commons/dbcp2/BasicDataSource.html)

```
getDefaultQueryTimeout 
[***]
Returns:
The default query timeout in seconds.

getValidationQueryTimeout
[***]
Returns:
the timeout in seconds before connection validation queries fail.
```

You could also read the [source code of this class](https://github.com/apache/commons-dbcp/blob/commons-dbcp-2.7.0/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/dbcp2/BasicDataSource.java) for more informations

Comment: OK problem solved. I'm using older version, but the documentation on their side is also not very fresh ;) 
I'm glad to see they've updated the javadoc.

Answer (score 0):

[defaultQueryTimeout](https://github.com/apache/commons-dbcp/blob/2ee3c53e75e9ad899ed2aa06bfd882ebeea7b4a2/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/dbcp2/PoolableConnectionFactory.java) is defining timeout in seconds according to code/Java docs

> Default query timeout in seconds